# Сортировка выдачи адресов по удаленности от геолокации юзера

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Газ, помогите разобраться, пжл, как оптимизировать поисковую выдачу адресов. Например, я выбираю свое местоположение в МСК при входе на сайт, иду выбирать адрес для доставки (например, Шаболовка - есть такая улица в МСК). Сейчас поисковый ответ начинается (собственно и заканчивается) адресом "река Шаболовка" где-то в Ярославской области.

Как оптимизировать поиск по локации юзера?

Answer (score 0):

У геокодера [есть параметры](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params.html?frpm=SO) для указания приоритетной области поиска. Это либо `bbox`, либо `ll`+`spn` на выбор. В пару к ним идёт параметр `rspn` — он указывает, надо ли искать только в заданной области или можно выходить за неё, если ничего не найдено.